# How to comment Apple's block extension for Doxygen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, doxygen, objective-c-blocks

[Doxygen announced in their changelog for version 1.7.2 to support Apple's block extension](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html). I wonder what the syntax is to generate the documentation. I could not find any hint - also not in the doxygen configuration file (version 1.7.2).
**Update:** Version 1.7.5 was released at August 14, 2011. Still I did not found out how to write documentation for Apple blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the diff between 1.7.1 and 1.7.2, I believe what is meant by this line is that the Doxygen scanner has been updated to support Apple's block syntax when recognizing **typedefs** for block types. For instance, you can document a function pointer typedef like this:

```
///
/// This is a typedef for a function pointer type. 
/// It takes an NSUInteger parameter, an id adopting protocol Foo, and has no return value.
/// 
typedef void (*MyFunctionPtrType)(NSUInteger p1, id<Foo> p2);
```

and get output like this:

[image: Doxygen output for function pointer typedef]

The changes to their scanner appear to add support for block typedefs like this:

```
///
/// This is a typedef for a block type. 
/// It takes an NSUInteger parameter, an id adopting protocol Foo, and has no return value.
/// 
typedef void (^MyBlockType)(NSUInteger p1, id<Foo> p2);
```

And indeed, with a recent version of Doxygen, that produces output like this:

[image: Doxygen output for block typedef]

You are able to document global variables of block types, but the behavior is a bit wonky. For instance, with this:

```
///
/// This is a global variable of type MyBlockType. It logs the parameters to the console.
///
MyBlockType myGlobalBlock = ^(NSUInteger p1, id<Foo> p2){

    /**
     * This is a block comment inside my block, which would get 
     * concatted into the "in body" description if this were a function.
     * but won't be because this is a block.
     */
    NSLog(@"p1: %lu p2: %@", p1, p2);
};

///
/// This is the definition for the function MyFunction
/// 
void MyFunction(NSUInteger p1, id<Foo> p2)
{
    /**
     * This is a block comment inside my function, which will get 
     * concatted into the "in body" description.
     */

    NSLog(@"p1: %lu p2: %@", p1, p2);
}
```

I get this output, which is kinda, sorta not what I want:

[image: Doxygen output for global block typed variable compared to a function]

Luckily, I suspect that global variables of block types aren't that common a pattern in practice, so the fact that Doxygen isn't super-great at handling them isn't such a big deal. There doesn't seem to be any evidence of any further added support for blocks in the diff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Obj-C, but here's how to tag the source to produce this output for the case where the type block is **not** a member of the interface.  Use the `@related` tag with the name of the related interface as its target:

```
/**
 * @related MyService
 *
 * The completion handler invoked when `unsubscribe` returns.
 */
typedef void(^MyServiceUnsubscribeCompletion)(NSError *error);


@interface MyService : NSObject
...
@end
```

Dimitri himself supplied the solution:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720046