# How to document Objective-C blocks with doxygen?

Tags: objective-c, documentation, doxygen, objective-c-blocks

I'm working on a doxygen-documentation based project and I can not figure out how to document a block. Let's imagine an asynchronous function with a block as callback

```
- (void)startWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))block;
```

How it should be documented this parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to comment Apple's block extension for Doxygen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916078/how-to-comment-apples-block-extension-for-doxygen)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) commenting a block would look like this

```
/**
 *@brief Short description
 *
 * Extended description
 *
 *@param[in/out/in,out] success
 *@param[in/out/in,out] error
 */
(void)startWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))block;
```

Comment: This answer describes how to create a comment block for Doxygen (correctly), not how to comment for the block parameter (as the question asked). As far as I've been able to tell, Doxygen doesn't recognize the block for what it is.

Comment: The syntax is wrong actually. In that way, you are saying that your method has 2 parameters: `success` and `error`, but that is wrong 'cause actually you have only 1 which is `block`.

Comment: This results in a -Wdocumentation clang warning: "Parameter 'success' not found in the function declaration. Did you mean 'block'?"